# Strange chars on HTML output... in PHP

Tags: php, text, utf-8, character-encoding

Character Ã³ = ó and all TILDES... PHP is corrupting the output!!

In the file I have `ó`

Output :

```
Ã³
```

***I have charset=UTF-8 ... but in the navigator the Character Encoding is setted to ISO-8859-1 I don't know why...***

What to do?

Answer (score 2):

It is probably not PHP. It would probably be that either the web server is enforcing an encoding (which is different from your file's), or you have not specified the correct output encoding.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the content is sent correctly but the browser fails to detect the encoding scheme. You can check for this by trying to force the encoding in your browser. For instance in Firefox : View > Character Encoding > Unicode (UTF-8)

In this does solve the output problem, try to add this before any content is output.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Alternatively, you can try those functions if you have the `mbstring` module installed. Set them to the encoding you are using.

- `mb_http_input`
- `mb_http_output`
- `mb_internal_encoding`
- `mb_regex_encoding`

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely to do with the content type in your HTML Doc. Your HTML doc is serving up a content type different to the file your coding in. But you haven't provided much information.

Comment: You have reason on that, I have charset=UTF-8 ... but in the navigator the Character Encoding is setted to ISO-8859-1 I don't know why...